# What is the scope of an imported function

Tags: python, import

If I have a python file as follows

```
import time

class abc:
    def func1(self):
        while True:
            do something
            time.sleep(5)

xyz = abc()
xyz.func1()
```

The above works exactly as expected

If I move the class definition out to a seperate .py file and import it

```
import time
from test1 import abc

xyz = abc()
xyz.func1()
```

Works as expected until it hits the time.sleep(5) when it errors
saying time is not defined

I have tried adding the time import into the class definition but
still seem to get the same problem
What am I missing.

Moving the import to the class definition file doesn't seem to resolve the problem, either adding it at the top or in the **init** .

Comment: Imports are not global (actually, NOTHING is).  If a module needs `time`, then you need to `import time`.  Add it ti `test1`.  It will work.

Comment: Unlike other languages. Python does not have a problem with duplicate imports. Just have them in every file/module that requires them.

Comment: Just add `import time` into your separate.py file.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had tried that but maybe I missed something. I will try again with some cut back code.

Comment: _Moving the import to the class definition file doesn't seem to resolve the problem_ - why, what happens? That is exactly what you should do

Comment: The only way I seem to be able to get this to work is by adding the import time within the def func1(): block. That's OK I can do that, but it doesn't feel like the right thing to do

Comment: class abc:
    import time
    def __init__(self, modem):
        .....

    def receive_data(self):
        .....

    def send_data(self, message_text):
            #do something
            time.sleep(5)

=========================
Main Program
    from test1 import abc

    xyz=abc()
    xyz.send_data('Test message')

Results in the following error

    time.sleep(5)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [python documentation about the import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

Quote from there:

> define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs.

So your toplevel import is bound on module level and the name `time` is accessible from wherever in that module.

If you move the import inside the method, it will be accessible in the local scope of the method and won't be visible outside of that method.

So, you don't want to move the import in your other module, as you don't use it there. To make things work, you should preserve the import of `time` where it is now and only move your function calls outside:

```py
# test1.py
import time

class ABC:
    def func1(self):
        while True:
            # do something
            time.sleep(5)
            print('slept 5 secs')
```

```py
# main.py
from test1 import ABC

abc = ABC()
abc.func1()
```

[Not related to your question tip] You should also take a look at [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) and follow it's conventions.